# RDP Wrapper Library by Stas'M and multisession

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, patch

http://stascorp.com/load/1-1-0-63
I'm using this patch to enable RDP on Win7 and enable multi-loggon to the 1 account for 2 users. But there is some problem. When i connect to the 1 account when other user already logon to this account we both use 1 session (when i move mouse then it moves on the other client side). I need to create 2 differrent sessions of 1 account like in 2003 server (for example 2 users can use one account without disturbing each other). How can i do this with that patch?

Comment: http://stascorp.com/load/1-1-0-63 blocked by avast as infected ...

Comment: That's not a patch, it's a hack violating the MS Eula. Anyway. The system does not behave like a normal terminal server. You should ask at stascorp if there is a solution.

Comment: [Virus total result for that site](https://www.virustotal.com/de/url/a64ef52928093e81dff81acf735429441b494095ac0fe436a0653b19cded9c89/analysis/1419803785/)

Comment: The github download scans fine for me on windows defender

Comment: support for tools which hack Windows functions is offtopic for me. Ask it on github in the issues section of the project.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hack violating the MS Eula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDP Wrapper includes a configuration program.

Leave blank checkbox "Single Session Per User" and click Apply.

---

Also you may change this setting in registry:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fSingleSessionPerUser /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```